Semantic Kernel plugin not working with ollama and phi3
Following this nice tutorial: https://laurentkempe.com/2024/05/01/run-phi-3-slm-on-your-machine-with-csharp-semantic-kernel-and-ollama/ I have set up my local model. And the chat part works just great. But if I try to create an agent following this description: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/semantic-kernel/overview/?tabs=Csharp, my plugin is not called. I get no error, just an answer, that it can't do what I want it to do.
Is this because of the limitations / a missing feature of Ollama?
[Update, 24-05-21]:
yes, it is missing: https://github.com/ollama/ollama/issues/4386

I'm having the same issue now, thanks for the link to the GitHub issue.
